# Spark Scala Kmeans - how to label results and visualize?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-ml

Here's some code that uses Spark ML to find clusters:

```
val dfRaw = spark.read.option("header", "true")
   .csv("src/main/resources/input.csv")
val K = 5
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("id", "lat", "lon")).setOutputCol("features")
val df = assembler.transform(dfRaw).select("features")    
df.show(false)    
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(K).setSeed(1L)
val model : KMeansModel = kmeans.fit(df)  
println("cluster centers")
model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
println("----- predictions")
val predictions = model.transform(df)
predictions.collect().foreach(println)
```

The input file is made up of the following 4 cols:  id, name, lat, lon

I'm sure I'm doing some stupid things in this code, but it kind of works (I think).  Any advice on improving it appreciated.  I'm wondering if the id column is affecting how it clusters the data.

I'm also struggling to make sense of the results.  What's a good way to join predictions (a DF of Vector) with the name column of dfRaw?

Also, I'd like to visualize the results on some kind of free grid or geomap, any recommendations?

Comment: Do you train (`kmeans.fit(df)`) your model on the same dataframe  that you're using when you trying to predict the results (`model.transform(df)`)?

Comment: Yes.  I was only interested in clustering this small amount of data as a learning experience--to get a better understanding of spark ml and clustering.  I assume in a real world situation I would have a set of data for training and then a new different set for testing and for predicting.  I ended up joining the Dataframes on the lat and lon, and I experimented with vega-s for visualizing it.